# What is the time complexity of the merge step of mergesort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I know this algorithm has a time complexity of o(nlogn), but if we speak about only the merge step, is this one still o(nlogn)? Or is it reduced to o(logn)? I believe the second is the answer but since we still have to touch every element in the array, I'm suspecting the complexity remains the same

Cheers!

Comment: It depends the merging you are using. Traditionally everybody uses the O(n) merging. I will be more than happy to see an O(lg n) merge.

Comment: You're absolutely right. The "split" step is the one that takes o(logn), and the merge one is o(n). I was confusing the time complexities. This solves my question. Thanks!!!

Comment: The split step time complexity for an array is O(1). The issue is that it takes log2(n) levels of recursion for top down merge sort or log2(n) iterations for bottom up merge sort, and O(n) for the merges for each level of recursion or each iteration, so the total is O(n log(n)).

Comment: There are two possible questions here: 1. How much total time is spent merging during a mergesort, as a function of the length of the array being sorted? 2. How much time is spent on a single merge, as a function of the length of the arrays being merged? These two questions have very different answers; and it's possible that the reason you are getting confused is that you are conflating them.

Comment: There would be (n-1) comparisons each requiring a unit of time.Hence when we choose comparison as the basic operation, the time efficiency for the merging step would be O(n).

Answer (score 4):

The "split" step is the one that takes o(logn), and the merge one is o(n), just realized that via a comment.

Comment: The split step doesn't take O(log n) time. That also takes time O(n). The O(log n) factor arises from summing up the work needed to perform all the merges across all levels of the recursion.

Comment: The split step calls mergesort recursively on 2 subsets or length n/2. This takes `O(1) + 2*(n/2)*log(n/2)` and the merge step has linear time: `O(n)`. Combining the 2 gives O(n.log(n)).

Answer (score 1):

The split step of Merge Sort will take O(n) instead of O(log(n)).
If we have the runtime function of split step:

T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(1)

with T(n) is the runtime for input size n, 2 is the number of new problems and n/2 is the size of each new problem, O(1) is the constant time to split an array in half.

We also has the base case: T(4) = O(1) and T(3) = O(1) .

We might come up with (not really accurate):

T(n) = n/2 * O(1) = O(n/2) = O(n)

Moreover, to understand the time complexity of Merge step (finger algorithm), we should understand the number of sub-array.

The number of sub-array has the asymptotic growth rate at the worst case = O(n/2 + 1) = O(n).

The "Finger Algorithm" grow linear with the growth of number of sub-array, it will loop through each sub-array O(n), and at each sub-array at the worst case it will need to loop 2 more times -> the time complexity of merge step (finger algorithm) = O(2n) = O(n).

Answer (score 0):

```
T(n) =T(n/2) +T(n/2) + θ (n) 
=2T(n/2) + θ(n) 
  =2T(n/2) + c.n
  So, Time complexity of Merge procedure 
  is  θ(n)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Where does  θ (n) come from? The other answer suggests O(1).